# Export from Excel to SQL Server with Excel Column of Multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I am fairly new to database design although I have some SQL skill. I have an excel sheet that I wish to upload to SQL Server. The issue is I have a column in Excel that has multiple values separated by "/".

For example:

`Fruit
Banana/Pear/Orange
Pear/Raspberry/...
Banana`

...

I want to split the cell based on "/" which I am fine doing. Then put the values into a table in SQL Server. However, there is no defined amount of "Fruits" that can be in the Excel cell so I need to allow for multiple table fields.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this? I wrote an ADODB connection to export from Excel to SQL Server but don't know how handle this cell.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to split your data after it has been loaded.  For example

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Fruit varchar(150))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'Banana/Pear/Orange'),
(2,'Pear/Raspberry/Apple'),
(3,'Banana')


Select A.ID
      ,B.Key_Value
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.Fruit,'/')) B
```

Returns

```
ID  Key_Value
1   Banana
1   Pear
1   Orange
2   Pear
2   Raspberry
2   Apple
3   Banana
```

The UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Comment: Got it! Ill work on implementing (as my actual database is a bit more complicated that fruit haha). Thank you

Comment: can you use .value on varchar?

Comment: @user3697498 Yes indeed

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Bridge Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). This way each row in Fruit table can have N types.

[image]

Description values in table Types will be Banana, Pear, Orange, Raspberry, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you design the table it will have to have a defined number of columns.

The simplest approach would be to assign an ID for each group.

```
ID  Fruit
1   Banana
1   Pear
1   Orange
2   Pear
2   Raspberry
3   Banana
```